# changing UIBarButtonItem on the QLPreviewController does not work on iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationitem, qlpreviewcontroller

I am inheriting `QLPreviewController` to set my own right button with my own handler.
It works fine on iOS 5.1, and I even managed to get it to keep the button after switching to Home and than back to my app.

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(openWithPressed:)]];
```

On iOS 4.3 the QuickLook appears with the standard buttons in the `UINavigationItem` (The right button is an "Open With" button, instead of my custom "Edit" button, with custom logic). Is there some known issue with setting the buttons in such a way? Should I do it in some other way?